# cdrom is not recognized

Tags: mount, cd-drive

I'm running precise pangolin on my laptop and always keep it updated. I've had some problems with the cdrom not being recognized by K3b before, but got it fixed by changing the permissions. But this time it seems that it is totally vanished from my computer. I've tried many different things that users had suggested on this website and many other websites, but none seems to work. Ironically, it works just fine when I boot to windows.

Here is the output of some commands:

```
$ sudo wodim --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (0 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and

```
 $ sudo depmod -ae
```

doesn't seem to do any good for me.

Also, for some reason there was no /dev/cdrom or /dev/cdroms or /dev/dvdrom folder on my computer. Nothing even similar to that.

My fstab looked like this:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=50424cf6-6dd8-4d34-a441-dd964f67ea97 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=ebf67e0f-3597-4ed9-bedc-73a4e8049071 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=e22d709a-c084-4fbf-bad3-2fef352e7e75 /home           ext4    defaults,user_xattr        0       2
UUID=94ca0e7c-e4bc-43b6-993f-fd140b6db7bd none            swap    sw                  0       0
```

and I added different things like the following:

```
 /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom iso9660 noauto,ro 0 0
```

but none of them helped.

And finally

```
$ dmesg | grep cdrom
```

returns nothing.

I'm not very familiar with technical things, I just tried all the different things suggested by others. Any help would be appreciated.

--

There are nothing related to cdrom in lshw, but in the output there are some unclaimed things:

```
$ sudo lshw
*-core
  [...]
  *-pci
    [...]
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 03
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:a0100000-a01000ff ioport:1c20(size=32)
 *-remoteaccess UNCLAIMED
   vendor: Intel
   physical id: 1
   capabilities: inbound
```

I'm not sure if it is something related or not!

Comment: What about `sudo lshw`? Can you see any cdrom related entry?

Comment: @EricCarvalho, Nothing related to cdrom. But there are a few UNCLAIMED things there. I added them to the original post.

Comment: If you don't mind I'd like to see your dmesg. Open `/var/log/dmesg`, copy its content and paste it on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ . Post here the pastebin URL (e.g. http://paste.ubuntu.com/1234567/).

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1099213/

Comment: Thanks for the help @EricCarvalho. I can't really use that method on my laptop though.

Answer (score 1):

I google it and found a lot of similar problems, most of them with no solution. But a couple of guys managed to solve this problem by changing the SATA port connected to the CD-ROM.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=125686